# Mathematical Algorithm Implementation in Spring Cloud Config YAML File

Tags: java, spring-boot, sdk, yaml, spring-cloud-config

**Context:**

I'm working on a Java SDK that wraps the library which analyzes provided text. As part of analyzing process, I want to run mathematical algorithms (validators) on findings. The new validators can be added during the time, and existing validators can be modified.

Once SDK is initiated by the client, it calls to **spring-boot** service to retrieve relevant configuration (**spring-cloud-config**)

My problem is, that I want to make my SDK as immutable as possible. In other words, all changes (including validators) to SDK logics should be added as external configuration, and not as part of SDK. I mean, all the changes **should not require SDK version change**.

**Challenge:**

How to implement mathematical algorithms (such [Luhn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm)) in the YAML configuration file and to convert it to Java code.

** Other implementation suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you could make the core of your SDK immutable. Create a interface called `MathematicalAlgorithm` in the core of your SDK, then create another module with just the implementations of it. The module called `mathematical-algorithms-implementations` will be mutable (you add new implementations to it), while the module called `mathematical-implementations-core` would be as immutable as possible (you would not have to add new algorithm implementation, but, instead, use the implementations from the other module).

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the solution, module `mathematical-algorithms-implementations` will be part of SDK, right? This means, that each change of this module will cause to change in the SDK version. And this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. 
Did I understand your suggestion right?

Comment: Perhaps change external configuration to external implementation.  The SDK could define an interface such as `Validator` that users of the SDK can implement, with the SDK providing some standard implementations such as Luhn.

Comment: @GeneZeiniss . . . Not exactly. Your `mathematical-algorithms-implementations` can have different version than the core. Nothing forces you to have the same version in both modules. That's why they must be different projects in the workspace.

Comment: @AndrewS
To get advanced with the external implementation you suggest I will need to upgrade the implementation version within my SDK (on validator change). This will make my SDK's client upgrade the SDK version as well,

Comment: @GeneZeiniss . . . yes, you will. The suggestion from Andrew is the same as mine and I think it's the best way to go. Java doesn't have a "eval" function like the one from Javascript. So don't expect to write Java code as text and then call some function to make the code run (which is exactly what the eval function from Javascript does). Anyway, if you still want to follow in that line, I suggest you to take a look at the `ScriptEngineManager` from the Java, which let's you execute arbitrary strings as a scripting language, such as Javascript, but, imo, this is not a good solution.